# How to maintain tableview index path.row value for hidden cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a table view that has a play button. I have assigned `button.tag = index path.row`, but I have a functionality that allows hiding cells. When I hide the cell the play button plays first index song since `sender.tag`  is wrong

```
UIButton *playButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
playButton.tag = indexpath.row;
[cell addSubview:playButton];
```

I want to get the proper index path even when cells are hidden.

Comment: when you click button than you want indexpath value

Comment: can you post more code

Comment: You shouldn't rely on tags, and if you do, you should handle cell reuse; your code makes me suspect that you don't.  A better solution is to have your cell hold a reference to the actual data object to which it refers rather than an array index or have your play button call your tableview controller via delegation and have the view controller determine which file should be played based on the state of hidden cells

Comment: Why you are hiding cell ?you can use the view of cell

Answer (score 0):

Firstofall, you are adding button to a tableview cell. And then you are mentioning that cell will be hidden. So now if cell is hidden that means there will be no button visibility, then there will be no indexpath.row to that button.

Comment: i can able to hide some cells like if i have a 5 cells each cell having button if i click that button i has working fine and user have a option to hide some cells from than if he hide 12 cells among 5 ,when i click on 3 button cell it is playing first cell song .